# What is the best way to know if a string is a long or a Guid?

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, guid, long-integer

I have some strings in a text files representing object ids, sometimes the id is a long and other is a Guid, and I need to parse them.

The quick answer is obvious, for example trying to parse a Guid and it if fails, try to parse a long, but. Is there any good way (**elegant solution**) to know if a certain string is a long or a Guid?

```
  ee02b525-9755-4a07-a46d-37bb5b060fd2 (Guid)
  -48765 (long)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> The quick answer is obvious, for example trying to parse a Guid and it
>   if fails, try to parse a long, but. Is there any good way (elegant
>   solution) to know if a certain string is a long or a Guid?

No. [long.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zc2x2b1h.aspx) and [Guid.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.tryparse.aspx) is the way to go. Another possibility is to test if the string contains `-` but not in the beginning:

```
someString.IndexOf("-") > 1
```

This is a strong indication that this string is not an Int64. It could be a Guid. But it could be anything else. Of course if you know that there can only be Guids and longs in this file it could be a strong indication.